# Accessing hybris "/occ/v2/" is responding 404 after upgrading Spartacus storefront from 1.4 to 3.1

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I have updated my storefront Spartacus app from 1.4 to 3.1.
As per [Spartacus technical changes](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/technical-changes-version-3/) we need to change backend.occ.prefix from /rest/v2/ to /occ/v2/.

After changing this, backend service call urls are getting changed.

Before change I had below URL call,
https://localhost:4200/rest/v2/basesites?active=true&showExternalSites=true&fields=FULL.
It returns valid data.

After backend.occ.prefix change to /occ/v2/ am getting below URL call,

https://localhost:4200//occ/v2/basesites?fields=baseSites(uid,defaultLanguage(isocode),urlEncodingAttributes,urlPatterns,stores(currencies(isocode),defaultCurrency(isocode),languages(isocode),defaultLanguage(isocode)))&lang=en&curr=USD

It returns 404 error.

Do we need to change any configuration in hybris setup or need any other changes from Spartacus storefront.

I have **hybris version 1905.19**

Please help me to get this fixed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `backend.occ.prefix` as `/rest/v2/`. occ extension comming with version 2005. On the other hand I think you will get a lot of error with 1905 with spartacus, because a lot of services comming with occ extension. You need to develop all of them on 1905. You need to think about upgrading 2005 or later.

Comment: I think you mean "1905", not "1909"